# Django dynamic form subclass list

Tags: python-3.x, django

I'm trying to understand how can I define model as a class containing 2 integers and 1 charfield and then make it a part of another model.

[Example of data I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVjGE.png)

I guess in object oriented programming I should define model class like this:

```
class Component(models.Model):
    pipe_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    length = models.IntegerField()
    amount = models.IntegerField()
```

And then I don't know how can I use it with django models, it should be something like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    components_needed = ? LIST OF Component class ?
```

Also, since components needed size will wary for objects, it should be possible to extend it's size with button on a page, for example there could be 3 input fields and next to them would be "+" and "-" button to add/remove another set of 3 input fields

I spent entire day looking for solution, but at this point I'm not sure if django can handle this. I'm new to python and django, so there are many things I do not understand.

I will be grateful for any kind of help

Comment: Can you use the same component for a multiple items?

Comment: Yes, those could be reusable for other items

Answer (score 1):

the only way now( you canot put multi FK in one cell) is like django itself using with user/groups so you need 3 models.
in django there is group, user and user_group so i suggesting for you:

```
class Component(models.Model):
    pipe_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    length = models.IntegerField()
    amount = models.IntegerField()


class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()


class Item_Component(models.Model):
    Component = models.ForeignKey(Component, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

so now in third model you can have multiple rows with item and with diffrent component.

open yours db viewer app and see django user_group table.